# Common drawer layout to all component react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to have a common drawer layout to all the components, So what i did is like drawerlayout as a component with all links in it, with props.children inside DrawerLayoutAndroid, and it is rendering the initial page, But in this component i'm not able to access this.props.navigator

home.js

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Welcome User </Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}> Your new token is {this.state.accessToken} </Text>
    </View>
  </DrawerLayout>
```

in DrawerLayout.js

```
  render() {
var navigationView = (
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.redirect.bind(this, 'qr_code')} style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
        Scan code
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
        Logout
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);
//We check to se if there is a flash message. It will be passed in user update.
let flashMessage;
if (this.props.flash) {
   flashMessage = <Text style={styles.flash}>{this.props.flash}</Text>
} else {
   flashMessage = null
}
return(
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
      {this.props.children}
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
);
```

}
}

there is a redirect function, where i try t navigate to other component and this.props.navigator.push is not a function